# Sort Facebook comments plugin by likes

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, plugins, comments

I'm writing specs for a page where there will be a Facebook comments plugin on every subpage.

We want the comments to be sorted by number of likes - is that possible?

I'm sure it could be done the 'hackish' way by retreiving the comments in a Facebook query and then put together the comments box from scratch, but obviously we would prefer to just set this on the comments plugin if possible.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. It is not possible to do have the above. One can atmost set the comments to be sorted by social relevance, which boosts comments with many "likes", comments made by one's friends or the like
.

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, but it's coming. The feature you are searching for was [announced](http://mashable.com/2011/06/30/facebook-comments-box-sort/) (actually [here](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-media/comments-box-improvements/214873061881524)) already a half year ago, still nothing.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that. What you link to describe three new features: chronological sort, boosting comments and social ranking. Social ranking sort takes likes into account, but not just that which is what I want. Social ranking wil put your friends comments above comments with less likes.